# How can I convert a string of characters to an object type?

Tags: c++

I've wanted to create a program using the operator `new` in order to obtain the right amount of memory for a string of characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class String
{
private:
    char* str;
public:
    String(char* s)
    {
        int len = strlen(s);
        str = new char[len + 1]; // points to a memory
        strcpy(str, s);
    }

    ~String()
    {
        cout << "Deleting";
            delete[] str;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    String s1 = "who knows";
    cout << "s1=";
    s1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

The constructor in this example takes a normal `char*` string as its argument. It obtains space in
memory for this string with `new`; `str` points to the newly obtained memory. The constructor
then uses `strcpy()` to copy the string into this new space. Of course, I've used a destructor as well.

However, the error is: no suitable constructor exists to convert from const char[10] to "String".

I'm a total beginner when it comes to pointers and I'm trying to understand why my constructor doesn't work as intended.

Comment: String literals have type `const char[]` - so your constructor should take a `const char*` as argument

Comment: This seems to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/nFQxqL) fine for me.

Comment: @cigien you need a better compiler.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Really? Even without the `const` it compiles, and does the right thing on gcc9.3. Is that incorrect? clang seems happy too.

Comment: Warning: `String` does not observe [the Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) This will lead to problems when you use it in more complicated programs.

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you so much, but is adding ```const``` something specific to a certain compiler? I see that other editors will accept my first attempt.

Comment: Interestingly this does seem to be [slipping through the cracks](https://godbolt.org/z/nQK6kL).

Comment: Even if the compiler accepts it, it shouldn't. You are not allowed to assign pointer to constant data to a pointer to non-constant data because of the obvious problems you can have if the program uses the non-constant pointer to write to memory that cannot be written.

Comment: @user4581301 That's true. I was just confused by a previous comment. I thought I was not compiling something correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, *some* compilers will accept your code (depending on how strict they are). For example, `MSVC` will accept it when ["conformance mode"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2019) is disabled - specifically, the [`/Zc:strictStrings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-strictstrings-disable-string-literal-type-conversion?view=vs-2019) option.

However, to fully conform to strict C++ rules, you need to supply a constructor for your `String` class that takes a `const char*` argument. This can be done readily by just 'redirecting' that constructor to the one without the `const` keyword, and casting away the 'constness':

```cpp
    String(const char* cs) : String(const_cast<char*>(cs)) { }
```

An alternative (and IMHO far better) way is simply to add the `const` qualifier to your existing constructor's argument, as all the operations you do therein can be be done perfectly well with a `const char*` (you would then not actually need the non-const version):

```cpp
    String(const char* s) {
        int len = strlen(s);
        str = new char[len + 1]; // points to a memory
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
```

Without one or other of these 'amendments' (or something equivalent), you are passing the address of string literal (which is immutable) to a function (the constructor) that takes an argument that (in theory, at least) points to data that *could be* changed within that function; thus, a strict compiler is within its 'rights' to disallow this. As your constructor *doesn't* change the data, then you should have no problem qualifying its argument as `const`.